Is there a blockchain system team calling by phone for recovery fund
I was contacted on mars 2024 by blockchain team recovery using eamil adress like : @recoveringblockchain.com or @management-departement.com.
This team told me that I am a owner of a fund of 4.2 BTC worth of 261 224$ US.
It send me what it calls a wallet statement and a link to see the account on blockchain web site. It's not a full access.
To get full access to this account the recovery blockchain team ask me:

First:  send 0.03 BTC to activate my account
Second : send a copy of my licence driver and my bank statement
Third send: send 0.1 BTC 6 176,20 us $

The team doesn't show me all this steps in the first calling. It was progressive.
At the third step, I made a request for blockchain security departement. I send all documents and e-mail from this team. Blockchain security departement told this is scam and I have to stop conversation with this team.
But, the recovery team continues to call me using  blockchain lego and  what seems real whatsapp number from UK . This team insists that it's not a scam but it's from the blockchain system. It works Spratley from blockchain fiat wallet. They ask me to make decision and if I stop the process they will refund me the 0.03 BTC (First step from the  process) and the fund wil be closed. This team doesn't  have a web site and doesn't have a platform where I can maque a request. At this time, I realise that at the 3 third step I do the right thing by contacting blockchain seurity departement. But I have a dubt, is blockchain system real and is working separetly from blockchain.com fiat wallet with no web site and paltform? Is anybody here have a similar experience. Am I really woner of 4.2 BTC or is it a scam?

Is there a reason you yourself don't know if you own a wallet with that amount in it?

What you describe is typical for a scam operated by criminals looking for people who don't know how Bitcoin works and who can be made confused and panic into doing foolish things. I would cease all communication with them, block them and ignore them.


Is there a blockchain system team calling by phone for recovery fund

No.


eamil adress like : @recoveringblockchain.com or @management-departement.com.

Clearly deceptive/fake. They also contain spelling mistakes that would not be made by a genuine business.


This team told me that I am a owner of a fund of 4.2 BTC worth of 261 224$ US.

Criminals tell that lie to hundreds or thousands of people in the hope of finding at least one person that will be uninformed, greedy or gullible enough to become their victim. Criminals prey on widespread human weaknesses like this.


It send me what it calls a wallet statement and a link to see the account on blockchain web site.

It is easy to set up an account with fake details. It is easy to add any valid Bitcoin-address as a watch-only Bitcoin-address, even if you don't own that Bitcoin-address. Criminals do this to deceive their victims.


the recovery blockchain team ask me:
First: send 0.03 BTC to activate my account

The criminals succeeded in tricking you into giving them money. Now they know it is worth their while to work on you and keep tricking you.


Second : send a copy of my licence driver and my bank statement
...
I send all documents

If you sent them your driver licence and bank statement they can impersonate you and run up debts in your name or commit other crimes using your name knowing that the police will contact you first not them
Look for "Identity Theft" advice from your local police. For example, like   ActionFraud for people in the UK


Third send: send 0.1 BTC 6 176,20 us $

See Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?


the recovery team continues to call me using blockchain lego

Logos are easy to copy. They don't mean a thing.


and what seems real whatsapp number from UK

There's no way to tell, and anyone can anonymously obtain a UK phone number for peanuts. A UK number is no guarantee of honesty or truthfulness,


I have a dubt, is blockchain system real and is working separetly from blockchain.com fiat wallet with no web site and paltform?

Lots of different people, including lots of criminals, use the name "blockchain".
There is a genuine business that operates a website named blockchain.com, but they are not in charge of the Bitcoin blockchain. Just as the car rental company dollar.com is not in charge of the US dollar.


Am I really woner of 4.2 BTC

No


or is it a scam?

Yes
